# StreamReader.ReadLine and CR

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sockets

Am I being dense here? [StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) states that:

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r") or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n")

So, why doesn't this work as expected?

```
' Server
Dim tcpL as New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000)
tcpL.Start(1)
Using tcpC as TcpClient = tcpL.AcceptTcpClient(), _
s as NetworkStream = tcpC.GetStream(), _
sr as New StreamReader(s, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, True)
   Dim message As String = sr.ReadLine()
   Console.WriteLine(message)
End Using
Console.ReadLine()

' Client
Using tcpC as New TcpClient()
  tcpC.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000)
  Using s as NetworkStream = tcpC.GetStream(), _
  sw as New StreamWriter(s, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
     sw.AutoFlush = True
     sw.Write("Hello there!")
     sw.Write(vbCR) ' Note the CR terminator
     Console.ReadLine()
  End Using
End Using
```

The server will not return from `ReadLine` until a disconnect - even though CR is sent. If I change to a `vbLF`, or `vbCRLF` it'll return as expected.

Are the docs wrong, or am I screwing something up here....?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ReadLine` is waiting to see what the next character is. If it's a line feed, it wants to swallow it. If you write any other characters to the writer, that'll make it return the line too.

It's an unfortunate corollary of the historical confusion over line terminators. It would probably have made more sense for `TextReader` to remember that it needed to potentially swallow the next character it read (and return the line immediately) but such is life.

Comment: Ahh - makes perfect sense, and makes it perfectly useless - since the message ends in CR, there's no more data to send.

Comment: At minimum, the documentation should be more forthcoming about this quirk.

Comment: Oh boy! 2023 and still fell into this trap -_- ... btw working extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/8388138/7111561