# StreamReader.ReadLine not working over TCP when using \r as line terminator

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader, readline, networkstream

When I use only `\r` as a line terminator, the `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method doesn't work. It works if I use `Environment.NewLine`, `\r\n` or `\ra` ("a" being any character). Is this a bug? The same problem doesn't occurs when using MemoryStream instead of NetworkStream. What workarounds can I use if I can't change the protocol?

My service

```
Thread service = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
{
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 2051);
    listener.Start();
    using (TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        string inputLine = reader.ReadLine(); // doesn't work - freezes here
        writer.Write("something\r");
    }
});
service.Start();
```

My client

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 2051))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    writer.Write("something else\r");
    var message = reader.ReadLine(); // doesn't work even
                                     // if I remove the freezing point above
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [StreamReader.ReadLine and CR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099953/streamreader-readline-and-cr)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem with my own ReadLine method

```
public static class StreamReaderExtensions
{
    public static string ReadLineSingleBreak(this StreamReader self)
    {
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        char c;
        while ((i = self.Read()) >= 0)
        {
            c = (char)i;
            if (c == '\r'
                || c == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }

            currentLine.Append(c);
        }

        return currentLine.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to cover also the combined case you might want to include `if (c == '\r' && self.Peek() == '\n'){  self.Read(); }` in order to skip over a `\n` received right after a `\r`