# Read from NetworkStream to delimiter

Tags: c#, tcpserver

what is the best way to read from NetworkStream to some delimiter (for example "\n")

I have following code:

```
        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        var message = new byte[4096];

        while (true)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
            }
            catch
            {
                // Exception
            }
            Response(message);
        }
```

Problem is, that from client sends something like "Some text\n continues on newline" but I would like to answer first on "Some text", then accept next line and send response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to read a line then use [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your `NetworkStream` and call its `ReadLine` method:

```
NetworkStream strm = client.GetStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm);
String line = reader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: But can I specify delimiter?

Comment: @JanKirchner `StreamReader` only provides basic methods like `ReadLine` and `ReadToEnd` you have to implement your own methods for custom delimiters

Comment: @JanKirchner read the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387536/streamreader-readline-not-working-over-tcp-when-using-r-as-line-terminator
provides a custom implementation to the ReadLine method you can do the same for other delimiters