# Problems with sending data to remote socket from service

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I am using `NotificationListenerService` and I want to send data to remote socket when `onNotificationPosted()` is called.
But I have a problem that the socket is connected, but when I write something using `BufferedWriter` or any other output class, it never sends it to the remote socket, until I shut down the app and the service with android studio.
this is my code for sending the data:

```
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //     DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    //    outputStream.writeUTF(send_counter + " $title: " + title + " $mes: " + mes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "started sending info");
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    bw.write(send_counter + " $title: " + title + " $mes: " + mes);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                //    bw.close();
                    //  outputStream.writeInt(icon.length);
                    //      outputStream.write(icon);
                    Log.d(TAG, "info sent");
                    //    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

only after I completely stop the app using stop button on android studio, the server gets the message from the client.
This code is fine for sending a message because this code worked for me from the main app, but it makes problems only when the background service uses it.

this is my server code (c#):

```
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();

            PostToConsole("Phone has connected from: " + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address + ":" + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int res = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            while (res > 0)
            {
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, res);
                PostToConsole(data + ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address);

                buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                res = nwStream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a separete Service class and send the data into it. Do not forget to wakeup the device.

I mean, use `startService()` instead of `new Thread...`

use `new Thread...` into a new one.

Comment: the first chunk of code is a method inside the NotificationListenerService. so you mean that I should create a new service just for the communication with the server?

Comment: @EldarAzulay , yes

Comment: Same problem again with the new service. I am using the exact same code as above, I just wrote it in the `onStart()` method.

Comment: @EldarAzulay , I've found in your server's code that you are not catching 'new line separator'

Comment: @EldarAzulay , https://stackoverflow.com/q/8387536/1979882 read this question and answer

Comment: It didn't work. I did right as he did on the last link you sent. It makes the same problem, I get the data only after the app and service stops.

Comment: the `readLine()` method in `StreamReader` doesn't return anything at all.
Using `read()` I can get the message but again, only after the app is killed.